# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void SettingsFragment.loadFromSharedPreferences()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I try to invoke loadFromSharedPreferences() function from SettingsFragment in MainActivity with fragment variable, but fragment becomes null when I instance it. I tried findFragmentById() and findFragmentByTag() methodes and neither of them worked. Is there another way to do it? Why findFragmentById() methode won't work? I also tried to change FragmentLayout to ConstraintLayout and didn't work.

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentManager manager;
    SettingsFragment fragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //loadFromSharedPreferences()
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragment = (SettingsFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.settingsFragment);
        fragment.loadFromSharedPreferences();

        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        findViewById(R.id.imageMenu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });


        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        final TextView textTitle = findViewById(R.id.textTitle);

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                textTitle.setText(destination.getLabel());
            }
        });
    }

    //AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode will cause your activities to reload automatically
    public void ToggleTheme( boolean isChecked ){
        if (isChecked) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);

        }
        else{
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    }
}

SettingsFragment class:
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static final String SAVE_SWITCH = "saveSwitch";
    public static final String IS_CHECKED = "isChecked";
    Switch switchTheme;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        switchTheme = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchMode);
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences( SAVE_SWITCH , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       // loadFromSharedPreferences();
        switchTheme.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_CHECKED,false));
        switchTheme.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            //Scriere in fis SharedPreferences
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    editor.putBoolean(IS_CHECKED,true);
                    switchTheme.setChecked(true);
                    editor.apply();
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).ToggleTheme(isChecked);
                }
                else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    editor.putBoolean(IS_CHECKED, false);
                    switchTheme.setChecked(false);
                    editor.apply();
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).ToggleTheme(isChecked);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    //Citire din fis SharedPreferences
    public void loadFromSharedPreferences() {
        boolean ischecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_CHECKED, false);
        switchTheme.setChecked(ischecked);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).ToggleTheme(ischecked);
    }
}

SettingdFragment XML:

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsFragment"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass">
<!--    android:tag="settingsTag"-->

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginStart="131dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="137dp"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvDarkSide"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDarkSide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="@string/light_dark_mode"
        android:textColor="#F10000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switchMode"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/switchMode" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:text="Switch"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="@string/select_the_language"
        android:textColor="#F10000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDarkSide" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerSelectLanguage"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorBackground"
        android:text="Language"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.682"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.248" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First of all, the id `R.id.settingsFragment` does not refer to the fragment itself, but rather the `ConstraintLayout` that is part of the fragment's layout.

Secondly, you have not created the fragment at all, nor did you add it to your activity, naturally the `supportFragmentManager` would return null when you attempt to find your fragment.

**UPDATE**

Your sharedPreferences is null when you call `fragment.loadFromSharedPreferences()`, that is because the property `preferences` is initialized in your fragment's `onCreateView()` function. `fragment = new SettingsFragment();` just creates the fragment's instance, it takes time for the fragment's view to finish inflating. Access the preferences only when you are sure it has been initialized. Furthermore, you set your switch's check state on too many (wrong) occasions, which caused looping of the app. The check should be set programatically only once at the creation of the fragment's view, then the check state is changed by user interaction, no reason to change it programatically anywhere else. For your specific code to work, do:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static final String SAVE_SWITCH = "saveSwitch";
    public static final String IS_CHECKED = "isChecked";
    Switch switchTheme;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        switchTheme = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchMode);
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences( SAVE_SWITCH , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean initChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_CHECKED,false);

        switchTheme.setChecked(initChecked);

        // use clickListener instead. As the activity and the fragment is recreated when the theme is switched, 
        // the isCheckedListener was called every time as you call switchTheme.setChecked() above. Use clickListener
        // to react to user interction only.
        switchTheme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (switchTheme.isChecked()) {
                    editor.putBoolean(IS_CHECKED,true);
                    // editor.apply() may have a delay, editor.commit() saves the changes immediately
                    editor.commit();
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleTheme(true);
                }
                else{
                    editor.putBoolean(IS_CHECKED, false);
                    editor.commit();
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleTheme(false);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        switchTheme.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    // here `onCreateView` has finished, i.e. preferences has been initialized and we can safely access it.
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_CHECKED, false);
        // Then we tell the activity about this event.
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onSettingsFragmentViewCreated(isChecked);
    }
}
```

And for your activity:

```
...
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentManager manager;
    SettingsFragment fragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        // inflate the activity's view first
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // refer to this activity's fragment manager
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // create the fragment first
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        // attach it to this activity's default fragment container using the fragment manager
        manager.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "SettingsFragment").commit();
    }

    public void onSettingsFragmentViewCreated(Boolean ischecked) {
        // once the preferences are created, you can access them anywhere in the app using the corresponding name
        // SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences( SAVE_SWITCH , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        
        // but in our case we don't need the preferences itself
        toggleTheme(ischecked);
    }

    public void toggleTheme(boolean isChecked ){
        // improve conditions to avoid setting the same theme
        if (isChecked && AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() != AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            Log.d("AAAA", "switched to MODE_NIGHT_YES");
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        }
        else if (!isChecked && AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() != AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO) {
            Log.d("AAAA", "switched to MODE_NIGHT_NO");
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked, but now I get a nul pointer from my loadFromSharedPreferences() methode from SettingsFragment

Comment: I tried the update it stil makes fragment null. What can I do?

Comment: I tried to put the following code in onResume() methode in mainActivity : ,, // refer to this activity's fragment manager
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        manager.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "SettingsFragment").commit();
        fragment.loadFromSharedPreferences();" but didn't work. Whatever I do it makes my fragment null and sharedPreference and switchTheme null when I call loadFromSharedPreferences() in mainActivity.

Comment: copy paste mistake from my side. Please remove the line `fragment.loadFromSharedPreferences();`. It should not be in your code anymore, and the `loadFromSharedPreferences()` function should be deleted from your fragment, it is replaced by `onSettingsFragmentViewCreated()`

Comment: It doesn't give me a  null pointer anymore, but when I start the emulator the SettingsFragment appears on the profile fragment like a sticker. Even when I moe to another fragment it appears like that.

Comment: Seems like layout issue. Have you tried debugging your code? Try giving your fragment layouts `android:background="#FFFFFF", otherwise create a new question so that other people can answer. The original question was about fragment creation and I answered it with explanation and even rewrote code for you, so create new question.

Comment: I will try to change the layout and I will also add another question. Thank you for your help!:)))